# Creating numbered folder if one with the same name already exists using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I'm currently writing a windows batch file which needs to check if a folder with the current computer name exists. If it doesn't, it writes the folder with the name, but if it is already there, it appends a number at the end so that in the end I'd have a folder containing folder names like this

```
G:\logs\computer-1
G:\logs\computer-2
G:\logs\computer-3
G:\logs\...
```

so far, I tried using this piece of code

```
set usb=G:
SET logdir="%usb%\logs\%computername%"
FOR /L %%F IN (1,1,25) DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%usb%\logs\%computername%-%%F" (
md "%usb%\logs\%computername%-%%F"
SET logdir=%usb%\logs\%computername%-%%F)
goto :eof
)
ECHO %logdir%
```

but all I manage to do is exit the loop, not something I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocal

set dir=G:\logs\%computername%

set n=0
md "%dir%"||call :a %n%

rem rest of your script    

exit

rem the a label is set after the exit function to prevent it from
rem running in the actual script when it's not required.

:a
set /a n+=1
md "%dir%-%n%"||goto a
exit /b
```

This script will create numbered folders in the way you described.

In batch, the syntax for `set` is `set "foo=bar"`. Quotes are necessary when variables include syntax breaking characters, like & or |. Spaces do not require quotes when declaring variables. `set foo="bar"` sets foo to `"bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Creating All Folders At Once**

Based on the starting code in your question, this will produce a folder with an extension (1 through *max*) if it does not already exist in one call:

```
SET usb=G:

SET logdir="%usb%\logs"

SET max=25

FOR /L %%F IN (1,1,%max%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%logdir%\%computername%-%%F" ( 
    md "%logdir%\%computername%-%%F")
    )
```

Ex.

[image: Example Batch Folder Creation All At Once]

**Option 2 - Creating Folders Incrementally**

As a second option, the solution below will add an incremental file extension once per call (based on the total number of folders in the directory). Likewise, it disregards existing folders:

```
SET usb=G:

SET logdir="%usb%\logs"

FOR /f %%A IN ('dir /b /ad %logdir%^|find /c /v "" ') DO SET fcount=%%A

SET /a fcount+=1

IF NOT EXIST "%logdir%\%computername%-%%A" (
    MD "%logdir%\%computername%-%fcount%")
```

Ex.

[image: Example Batch Folder Creation Once Per Call]

**Caveats**

- The first solution will *always* produce folders 1 through *max*.
- The second solution has a weakness in that it uses the total folder count in a directory. So while it will produce similarly named folders with numerical extensions, true ordered sequences with no gaps (i.e. -1,-2,-3,-4...) require:

  - all folder names in a directory need to be the same.
  - any additional folders (e.g. those added manually) keep this sequence (i.e. if *computer-6* exists, the next manually added folder must be *computer-7*).

Comment: I just need something that will count up to prevent folder overwriting and indicate which folder came first and then second.